# Finding next/previous row in MySQL

Tags: mysql

My PHP page queries a Files table and users can click the columns on the page to sort by title, date, size, status and name of uploading user. They can then click on each file to view it in a separate player page.

What I'd like to do is create previous / next buttons in the player to go to the previous or next file **as ordered on the Files page**. This means that the results could be ordered by any of the parameters listed above.

For something like date, it's pretty simple:

```
SELECT * FROM Files WHERE date > curdate ORDER BY date LIMIT 1
```

However, some of the other parameters are causing me issues:

- How do I deal with strings like the name of the uploading user?
- How do I deal with situations where the next item in the sorted column has the same value? For example, status is an int between 0 and 3 and most files will have a status of 0. If I sort by status on the Files page, it lists all the files with status 0 first, then status 1, etc. So if my current file is in the middle of the 0 status files, how do I find out what the next one is that also has a status of 0?

(P.S. I know there are lots of threads on this topic but I haven't seen one addressing the specific situations above.)

Comment: there's lots of questions on a similar topic, with a lot of answers that don't really work. You've managed to identify a key problem of ordering on non-unique values. The "trick" is to order on something that IS unique... your "major" column first (what the user said he wanted things ordered by, and then your secret "minor" column, that gets you a unique identifier for the row. The "trick" is to use the values from the "last seen" row to start at the "next" row. An appropriate index will make this efficient, may more efficient than some other popular approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q: How do I deal with strings like the name of the uploading user?**

**A:** The same way you deal with dates and numbers. Strings are "orderable" too.

**Q: How do I deal with situations where the next item in the sorted column has the same value?**

**A:** The same way you'd deal with duplicate values for dates that aren't unique. In addition to the "major" sort column, you need another "minor" sort column which is unique, or the combination of "major" and "minor" together is unique.

Ideally, you'd have a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY on non-nullable column that can serve as the "minor" sort order.

The "trick" is to save the current position in the list, by saving major and minor values the "last seen" row, and then use that information in the query to get the "next" page.

```
    WHERE t.major >= :last_seen_major
      AND (t.major > :last_seen_major OR t.minor > :last_seen_minor)
    ORDER BY t.major ASC, t.minor ASC
    LIMIT 1
```

From the last row (in this case, just one), you'll want to save the values of the major and minor columns, so that those can be used in the same query, to get the "next" row.

For best query performance, you'll want an index available with leading columns of `(major, minor)`.

Based on your query, assuming you have an `id` column, you'd do something like this:

```
SELECT f.*
  FROM Files f 
 WHERE f.date >= :last_seen_date
   AND (f.date > :last_seen_date OR f.id > :last_seen_id)
 ORDER BY f.date ASC, f.id ASC
 LIMIT 1
```

To order by some other column, replace `f.date` in the WHERE and ORDER BY clauses with something else, e.g. `f.name`.

---

**A less performant alternative**

The other really popular approach is to use an "offset" in the LIMIT clause.

At first blush, this appears to be an elegant solution, but it does have some troubles.

You could do:

```
ORDER BY major ASC, minor ASC LIMIT 41,1
```

For the "next" row, you increment the offset by 1

```
ORDER BY major ASC, minor ASC LIMIT 42,1
```

One problem with this approach, if a row is inserted in the range of rows already seen, the "next" query will return the same row. Because what was the 41st row is now the 42nd row. If someone deletes a row, the "next" query will skip a row. And I'm not willing to live with that kind of defect in my "get the next row" function. And this approach still needs to keep track of the position in the list, but by carrying an additional offset which is not really part of the row.

Another problem with this approach is that the database has to retrieve the rows, then order them, and then finally apply the LIMIT clause, which can be a performance issue with large sets.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. To be honest, I wasn't entirely sure how to use the bind variables so I removed the colons and referenced the current value of the variable and this worked fine in my testing. 

My code looks something like this:


`SELECT f.*
  FROM Files f 
 WHERE f.date >= $date
   AND (f.date > $date OR f.id > $file_id)
 ORDER BY f.date ASC, f.id ASC
 LIMIT 1`


And for finding the previous file it's virtually the same but with the > reversed and sorting by descending order instead.